Why don't my switch wires show voltage?
I wanted to replace some old dimmer switches with new ones. After installing the new switches nothing worked. So I started moving wires and that's when things got out of hand.
I have two cables leading to can lights in the ceiling. Those 2 cables have 2 white wires and 3 black wires. It looks like one of the black wires was spliced into the cable. I can't really tell because it is in the wall, all I see is the vee formed and electrical tape. The three black wires are just hanging at this point.
The white wires are tied together in the box. There is another white wire that is coming from an outlet on the other side of the wall.
I used a multimeter to check for voltage and found that the three black wires have no voltage. The 2 white wires that are tied together have no voltage. The white wire coming from the outlet is hot (120 volts).
I checked the main breaker box to see if anything was loose and all of those wires appear to be snug.
I knew I should have tagged the wires before taking the switches out, so I am putting this one in the "lesson learned" file.  Any help that you can provide is appreciated.
Here is a picture with the white hot wire tied to the other white wires.


Pictures of the wires will help.  Concern about the hot white.  Getting power from the outlet is okay, but should be with a black/white cable, not a single white.

Usually you have a hot white when using a switch loop and get the power from the light fixture.  With two whites/neutrals connected in the box, you do not have a switch loop, so should not have a hot white there.

Crip659 - Thank you for your information.  If I remove the white wire coming from the outlet then the outlet does not work.  I looked at the outlet wires and it has the black side coming from another switch (dining room) and the white side is going from the other side of the outlet to the white wires in the box. Suggestions??

You seem to have, at a minimum, some nonstandard wiring here. Some of it seems illegal. Might be time to get an expert on site.

Crip659 - So if I am reading your post correctly, I should replace the single white wire and install a normal cable from the outlet into the box.  Then if I am correct, the white will tie in with the other white wires and the remaining black wire becomes the load wire?  If that is so, then my problem is solved.

Can you attach pictures of the wiring at the outlet?  Did the lights work before you replaced the switches?  Does the circuit breaker trip when connecting the white hot wire to the other two whites as shown in your picture?

Mark 31 - The breaker did not trip when the hot white was added.  I am in the middle of replacing the wires between the outlet and the box.  This is what I have found so far:  The existing cable was attached to the dining room switch, it ran to the outlet where the black side was attached to the hot side and the white was attached to the neutral.  From there a single white wire was run from the neutral side back to the box.

Problem solved - I replaced the white wire coming from the outlet and installed a new line.  Shout out to Crip659 for steering me in the right direction.  This website is by far the best thing for DIYs  Thanks again everyone.
